# Как исключить css код из js bundle?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, less

Мне нужно создать набор React компонентов. Каждый компонент содержит свой js и css код, расположенный в отдельной папке. Например:

- Dialog

  - Container.jsx
  - Presentation.jsx
  - styles.less

На выходе необходимо собрать два отдельных файла: js и css bundles.
Вот часть моего webpack конфига:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            query: {
                presets: [
                    ['react'],
                    ['es2015'],
                    ['stage-0']
                ],
                plugins: [
                    ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
                    ['transform-runtime'],
                    ['transform-react-remove-prop-types'],
                    ['transform-react-constant-elements'],
                    ['transform-react-inline-elements']
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'less-loader']),
        }
    ],
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false,
        comments: false,
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            sequences: true,
            booleans: true,
            loops: true,
            unused: true,
            warnings: false,
            drop_console: true,
            unsafe: true
        }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'bundle.css',
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
        assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/g,
        cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
        cssProcessorOptions: {
            discardComments: {
                removeAll: true
            }
        },
        canPrint: true
    })
],
```

Webpack создаёт `bundle.js` + `bundle.css`. Всё работает как надо за исключением одного момента. `bundle.js` содержит в себе css код из `bundle.css`.

К примеру, если размер файла `bundle.css` = 50KB, то размер `bundle.js` = собственный размер + 50KB.

Мне нужно исключить дублирующийся ненужный css из js bundle.

Если подключить плагин `babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore` и настроить его на игнорирование css/less, то `extract-text-webpack-plugin` перестаёт создавать bundle.css.

Comment: не уверен, что это лучшее решение, но я в таких случаях просто создаю js-файл, состоящий из одного только подключения css / yml / etc, сохраняю желаемое в отдельном файле, а результирующий бандл просто не использую.

Comment: У меня была мысль проходить вебпаком два раза: первый раз создавать bundle.js + bundle.css (как есть сейчас), второй раз - с включённым игнором css, и перезаписывать bundle.js. Но это больше похоже на костыль. Хотелось бы найти более удачное решение.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка исчезла с переходом от `laravel-elixir-webpack-official` к нативному `webpack` (webpack-stream)